# Accessing uiOutput Value On App Load

Tags: r, shiny

To simplify this example I've only included the necessary code to describe the issue I'm having.  Should it be required, I will include a fully reproducible example, but I have a hunch that this issue can be solved through theory alone by someone with more experience using Shiny.  Basically, I've programmed a Shiny app in R which looks something like this:

**ui.R**

```
plotOutput(outputId = 'heatmap1', height = "800px")
uiOutput('selectStrains')
uiOutput('selectRegions')
```

**server.R**

```
output$selectStrains = renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId='strains',
                     choices=sort(colnames(mousedata)),
                     selected=colnames(mousedata))
})
  output$selectRegions = renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId='regions',
                     choices=sort(rownames(mousedata)),
                     selected=rownames(mousedata))
})

# more code

output$heatmap1 = renderPlot({
    input$recalculate
    mousedatamat = as.matrix(mousedata[isolate(input$strains), isolate(input$regions)])
    heatmap.2(mousedatamat)
})
```

**problem:**

My problem is that in `server.R`, when the app is first loaded, `input$strains` and `input$regions` are both NULL.  Therefore, `mousedatamat` in `server.R` will be a 0x0 matrix, and the heatmap will be empty on the front page of the app, which makes for a pretty poor user experience.  I don't know how the `ui.R` and `server.R` files interact when an app is launched, so I'm finding it difficult to debug.  To make the plot show up I either need to click a recalculate button (`input$recalculate`), or resize the window (but only in the horizontal dimension for some reason).

To add more mystery to the mix, I have the same heatmap figure on page 2 (I'm using a navbarPage layout), which shows up on the app load when I navigate to that tab!  It is the very same code, only instead it is assigned to `output$heatmap2`.  When I navigate back to page 1, `output$heatmap1` still does not display.

I've tried placing the calls to `uiOutput` above `plotOutput` in `ui.R`, but the main reason I don't know how to solve this I think is because I don't know much about execution flow when an app is started.  Any ideas or information on this topic?

Comment: I think a full example can make easier to reproduce the issue

Comment: I agree with @mucio, for this type of error debugging we need to be able to replicate it before we can solve it, please provide a minimally reproducible example.